# How to remove empty [''] from string in python from Text file

Tags: python-3.x, string

```
file = open("file path", "r") 
links = file.read().split("\n")
print(links)
```

looks like this `['https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCWTgK00SCKKNgpbsAgqzUxw/videos','https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Dkl1K3mtHM', '']`

I want it to be like this:
`['https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCWTgK00SCKKNgpbsAgqzUxw/videos','https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Dkl1K3mtHM']`

How can I achieve this? Are there any specific step i missed? How do i remove `''` from the list

**Original Text file:**
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCWTgK00SCKKNgpbsAgqzUxw/videos
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Dkl1K3mtHM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files usually have a blank line at the end of them so you could manually remove the last item:

```
links = file.read().split("\n")[:-1]
```

the `[:-1]` means "everything up to and NOT including the last element".

Alternatively you can filter all blank lines (including in the middle) with:

```
links = [line for line in file.read().split("\n") if line and not line.isspace()]
```

We use `list` here because `filter` returns a generator. `line and not line.isspace()` means first that the line is not empty (`''`) and second that it doesn't consist only of space characters.

Answer (score 1):

In cases where the `''` is not only at the end of the list, just iterate through the list while checking with a conditional while appending to a new list.

```
links = ['https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCWTgK00SCKKNgpbsAgqzUxw/videos','https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Dkl1K3mtHM', '']
new_links = []
for i in links:
    if i != '':
        new_links.append(i)
print(new_links)
```

This would return `['https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCWTgK00SCKKNgpbsAgqzUxw/videos', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Dkl1K3mtHM']`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `strip` for this

```
file = open("file path", "r")
links = file.read().strip().split("\n")
print(links)
```

**strip()** is an inbuilt function in Python programming language that returns a copy of the string with both leading and trailing characters removed (based on the string argument passed).